# Using ConvertRecord on compressed input

Tags: zip, compression, apache-nifi

In [Apache NiFi](https://nifi.apache.org/) I can have an input with compressed data that's unpacked using the [UnpackContent](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-standard-nar/1.9.2/org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.UnpackContent/index.html) processor and then connect the output to further record processing or otherwise.

Is it possible to operate directly on the compressed input? In a normal programming environment, one might easily wrap the record processor in a container that more or less transparently unpacks the data in a stream-processing fashion.

If this is not supported out of the box, would it be reasonable to implement a processor that extends for example [ConvertRecord](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-standard-nar/1.5.0/org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.ConvertRecord/index.html) to accept a compressed input?

The motivation for this is to work efficiently with large CSV data files, converting it into a binary record format without having to spill the uncompressed CSV data to disk.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Compressed input for record processing is not supported currently, but is a great idea for improvement.
Instead of implementing it at a particular processor (e.g. ConvertRecord), I'd suggest following two approaches:

1. Create CompressedRecordReaderFactory implementing RecordReaderFactory

   - Like Java compressed stream such as GZIPInputStreawm, CompressedRecordReaderFactory will wrap another RecordReaderFactory, user specifies compression type (or the reader factory may be able to implement auto-detect capability by looking at FlowFile attributes ... etc)
   - Benefit of this approach is once we add this, we can support reading compressed input stream at any existing RecordReader and Processors using Record api, not only CSV, but also XML, JSON ... etc
2. Wrap InputStream at each RecordReaderFactory (e.g. CSVReader)

   - We could implement the same thing at each RecordReaderFactory and supporting compressed input gradually
   - This may provide a better UX because no additional ControllerService has to be configured

How do you think? For further discussion, I suggest creating a [NiFi JIRA](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/NIFI) ticket. If you're willing to contribute, that would be even better.